# R geom_bar sum count by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset and I am trying to create a bar chart where the sum of the bars per group is 100%. In this example the sum of the two blue would be 100% and the sum of the white bars would be 100% as well. Any idea on how to do this? Below an  example.

```
specification <- c(1
                   ,1
                   ,1
                   ,1
                   ,1
                   ,1
                   ,1
                   ,2
                   ,2
                   ,2
                    )
positive <- c("Negative growth"
              , "Positive growth"
              , "Negative growth"
              , "Negative growth"
              , "Negative growth"
              , "Positive growth"
              , "Positive growth"
              , "Negative growth"
              , "Negative growth"
              , "Positive growth")

df <- data.frame(as.factor(specification), positive)


ch <- ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data = df
           , aes(x = as.factor(positive)
                 , y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..))
                 , fill = forcats::fct_rev(as.factor(specification))
                 , stat = "identity"

           ), position = position_dodge(width=0.5)
           , width = 0.4
           , colour = 'black') +
  scale_fill_manual( breaks = c("1"
                                , "2")
                     , values = c("blue"
                                  ,'white')
                     , name=""
                     , labels = c("specification 1",
                                  "specification 2"
                     )) +
  theme_bw() + theme(plot.title=element_text(size=16),
                     axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                     axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                     axis.text.y=element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
                     axis.text.x=element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
                     panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                     panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
                     panel.border = element_blank(),
                     legend.text=element_text(face="bold",size=8), 
                     legend.key = element_rect(colour=NA, fill=NA),
                     legend.background=element_blank(),
                     legend.key.height = unit(0.4, "cm"),
                     legend.key.width = unit(0.4, "cm"),
                     legend.position = 'bottom'
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
ch
```

Comment: You could try using `geom_bar(... position = "fill")`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(specification = factor(specification), positive)
df <- df[, .(y = .N), by = .(positive,specification)][, .(percent_positive = y/sum(y)*100, positive), by = specification]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = specification, y = percent_positive, fill = positive, color = positive))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

1. for dodged bars, you may use `geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9))`
2. for relabeling factor levels in specification, you may do `df <- data.table(specification = factor(specification, levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("specification 1", "specification 2")), positive)`

**Output:**

[image]

**Data:**

```
specification <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
positive <- c("Negative growth", "Positive growth", "Negative growth", "Negative growth", 
              "Negative growth", "Positive growth", "Positive growth", "Negative growth", 
              "Negative growth", "Positive growth")
```